# Date function on oracle

Tags: oracle, date-arithmetic, sql-date-functions

I've got a question about date function on oracle.

I have the following table

```
statistic_table(
   pages AS varchar(10),
   date_created AS date
);
```

I have the following sql

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM statistic_table WHERE date_created BETWEEN sysdate-5 AND sysdate-1
and
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM statistic_table WHERE date_created BETWEEN to_date('12-AUG-2011') AND to_date('16-AUG-2011');
```

the question is, why is it return different numbers. assuming sysdate-5 returns 12-aug-2011 and sysdate-1 returns 16-aug-2011

Any help would be much appreciated!

Cheers,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A date in Oracle is a point in time with a precision of a second.

`SYSDATE` returns the current date and time and is therefore not the same as `to_date('17-AUG-2011')`:

```
SQL> SELECT to_char(sysdate, 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') FROM DUAL;

TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD-MON-YYYYHH
------------------------------
17-aug-2011 15:52:13
```

Use the [`TRUNC`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions201.htm#i79761) function if you only want the date component:

```
SQL> SELECT to_char(trunc(sysdate), 'dd-mon-yyyy hh24:mi:ss') FROM DUAL;

TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE),'DD-MON
------------------------------
17-aou-2011 00:00:00
```

Comment: if I want to use sysdate, how do I make them to return the same number of rows? should I cast it? if so, how?

Comment: @gumpi: you can use the `trunc` function on `sysdate`

Answer (score 5):

sysdate - 5 will give you a date with the current time. So if I ran it at 1pm precisely, the query would be equivalent to:

```
select (*) 
FROM statistic_table 
WHERE date_created BETWEEN to_date('12-Aug-2011 13:00:00') 
                       AND to_date('16-Aug-2011 13:00:00')
```

whereas the second query is:

```
select (*) 
FROM statistic_table 
WHERE date_created BETWEEN to_date('12-Aug-2011 00:00:00') 
                       AND to_date('16-Aug-2011 00:00:00')
```

you should probably try this instead:

```
select (*) 
FROM statistic_table 
WHERE date_created BETWEEN trunc(sysdate) -5 
                       AND trunc(sysdate) -1
```

Answer (score 2):

Because SYSDATE includes a time component, so if the current time is 11:22:33, then

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM statistic_table 
WHERE date_created BETWEEN sysdate-5 AND sysdate-1
```

is actually equivalent to

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM statistic_table
WHERE date_created BETWEEN to_date('12-AUG-2011 11:22:33','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
                       AND to_date('16-AUG-2011 11:22:33','DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

To avoid the time component do this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM statistic_table 
WHERE date_created BETWEEN TRUNC(sysdate)-5 AND TRUNC(sysdate)-1
```

Answer (score 1):

An Oracle `DATE` always has a day and a time component.

`sysdate-5` returns a date exactly 5 days ago.  If today is August 17 at 10 AM, for example, `sysdate-5` returns August 12 at 10 AM.

`to_date('12-AUG-2011', 'DD-MON-YYYY')`, on the other hand, returns August 12 at midnight.  So it returns a date that is 10 hours earlier than `sysdate-5`.

Answer (score 0):

sysdate auto returns with a time component as mentioned by the previous answers.

When using to_date it is converting a string to a date. With this being said you can pass in parameters to make it return the same thing.

Have a look at this link that explains it.

[to_date parameters](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php)